# Twilio: I get "Participant is unavailable at the moment" in rejected call

Tags: java, android, ios, twilio, twilio-api

I'm currently working on the implementation of `Twilio Video` in my Android app, where the normal behavior (and the one I need) should be:
If client A calls a client B, and client B rejects the call, client A receives (`onConversation`) an error (object `TwilioConversationsException`) containing `code:107, message:Participant rejects the call.`. 
Or if client A calls client B, and client B isn't connected to Twilio, Client A receives an error immediately with `code:106, message:Participant is unavailable at the moment.`. At this point I retry several times until the user connects and responds (accepting or rejecting), or 30 seconds pass after the call was initiated.

I'm working based on this, but I've encountered an issue after client B loses internet connection or the app closes unexpectedly. After reconnecting to Twilio, when client B rejects a call, client A receives an error `code:106, message:Participant is unavailable at the moment.` instead of `code:107, message:Participant rejects the call.`, deceiving client A into thinking that cliente B is disconnected from Twilio (when he actually is connected), which triggers a new call try.  For what I've been observing, this problem is associated to the client B identity, where somehow it remained registered as `unavailable` and is not letting it work properly. If I change client B identity, the behavior goes back to regular, but it's not the idea. My intention is for the identity to be my users id: unique and fixed.
In iOS is happening the same, according to this thread:

[Twilio iOS Video Call: Getting "User is unavailable" error message when user rejects the call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38659489/twilio-ios-video-call-getting-user-is-unavailable-error-message-when-user-rej)

I would appreciated some help! Best regards!

Comment: Please spend some time to format your question, It's hard to understand in one line. Thanks.

Comment: Alex Badan, Ready, improve the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A co-worker asked Twilio support and was told this:

> Hey Deneb,
>
> These workflows have some challenges with the current Conversations
>   API in Programmable Video, and we're working on solving them in an
>   upcoming addition to the product: A new Rooms API. Rooms will allow
>   your users to connect to named Room (a multi-party conference call) by
>   a name that you define, or by its unique ID (RoomSid). Using this API,
>   you won't have to worry about if/when your endpoints are online--you
>   can just have your users connect to the proper Room and they'll be
>   able to share voice and video with one another.
>
> The Rooms API will be rolling out in just a few weeks, and I think
>   it'll be a much better fit for your use case. If you're in need of a
>   solution more urgently, I'd recommend using a third-party
>   notifications product, like Firebase or PubNub, to make sure that both
>   participants are "awake" and connected, then initiating the invite
>   flow.
>
> Let me know if you have any questions on this. Thanks for trying
>   Programmable Video,
>
> Regards, Rob Brazier